# Excel: Reference Dropdown Cell in Countif Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, data-validation, countif

I'm trying to substitute text in an excel formula with a cell reference to the text in a dropdown.

First formula that yields the correct answer is:

```
=(SUM(COUNTIFS('LP - All Properties'!G:G,{"Phoenix","Tucson"},'LP - All Properties'!L:L,"Leased")))/SUM(COUNTIF('LP - All Properties'!G:G,{"Phoenix","Tucson"}))
```

I want to replace the text "Phoenix" and "Tucson" with a cell reference to a dropdown containing those values.  However, this formula doesn't yield the proper result:

```
=(SUM(COUNTIFS('LP - All Properties'!G:G,{"C2","D2"},'LP - All Properties'!L:L,"Leased")))/SUM(COUNTIF('LP - All Properties'!G:G,{"C2","D2"}))
```

I also tried without the quotation marks around C2 and D2, but that also did not work.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter C2:D2 forms an array and thus you need to make it an array function.  The correct formula would be

```
=(SUM(COUNTIFS('LP - All Properties'!G:G,C2:D2,'LP - All Properties'!L:L,"Leased")))/SUM(COUNTIF('LP - All Properties'!G:G,C2:D2))
```

And then here comes to the tricky part - instead of hitting Enter finishing your input, you will need to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to let Excel knows it contains parameter to array function.

If you manage to do that correctly, the formula will look like `{=(SUM(COUNTIFS(...))}` with the `{}` parenthesis around the formula.

Comment: If you use SUMPRODUCT in place of both SUM functions you don't need "array entry"

Answer (score 0):

For a slightly different approach you could use `AVERAGE`, i.e. this "array formula"

`=AVERAGE(IF('LP - All Properties'!G:G=C2:D2,IF('LP - All Properties'!L:L="Leased",1,0)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

This only works when `C2:D2` is a horizontal vector